# Disable the natively generated identity value feature in grails

Tags: grails, identifier, generated, heidisql

The following is my Domain class details.

```
class Age {
    String agetype
    static constraints = {
    }

}
```

I am using HeidiSQL. I want to drop the id column that is generated automatically.And set primary key as 'agetype'. what I can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifier can be customized easily inside the mapping block, if the default `id` is not required.

```
class Age {
    String agetype

    static mapping = {
        id name: 'agetype', 
           column: 'AGE_TYPE', // if the column name is AGE_TYPE
           generator: 'assigned' // Unique String should assigned for agetype
    }

    static constraints = {
        agetype bindable: true //identifiers are not bindable by default
    }
}
```

With the above setup, you should be able to create Age as:

```
new Age(agetype: 'Teen').save(flush: true)
```

Above will through a primary key violation if run again.

Refer [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html) for more details about customizing `id` and [`column`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html) as required.

Comment: Wouldn't be necessary. Type can be inferred from the type of the field. In your case, I would suggest adding the column name because the name is not camelCased (ageType) and if the actual column name is `AGE_TYPE` then it won't automatically infer.

Comment: Its not working. Still the id coloumn is there and its the primary key. I want to drop the id field and make agetype as primary key. not rename the id field.

Comment: Make sure the table is re-created once the app is restarted after the above modification. Check if `DataSource.groovy` has `dbCreate = "create-drop"` in the concerned environment.

Comment: @Sag In that case it has to change to "create-drop" and then restart app, in order to drop the old table and create a new one with agetype as the primary key.

Comment: not workinng. I changed it to create-drop. and did all that you mentioned.but still not working.

Comment: now also the primary key is auto generated id field

Comment: My bad. There was a typo in my answer (rectified it). Should be `mapping` instead of `mappings` as `static mapping = { .. }`. Should work now after app restart.

Comment: @Sag See my update regarding usage of generator and bindable constraint.

Comment: it is not possible to give dbCreate="create-drop" in my case. since I have so many tables in my app, if i giv it like that i wil lose all the data in other table.

Comment: Then you should seriously look at the [database migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) and its usage which can come handy in this scenario OR just drop AGE table in the database directly and re run the app, that should do as well.

Comment: BTW if you already had run through my process using create-drop (as mentioned in your comment earlier), tables and data is lost and has been re created already. Isn't it?

Comment: I tried it in a sample project. cant integrate to my original app

Comment: Try again. This should work. Which version of Grails?

Comment: Is it still a problem? @Sag