# GORM Custom Primary Key

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

How to use custom primary key in Grials GORM, i have below domain class :-

```
class People {

    static mapping = {
        version  false
        }

    String people_id;
    String name;
    String apppassword;
    String card;
    String role;
    boolean visible;
    String phone;
    byte[] image;
    Date creationTime;
    Date modificationTime;
    static constraints = {

        id name: 'people_id', type: 'string'
        people_id(nullable: false )
        name(nullable: false)
        apppassword(nullable: true)
        card(nullable: false)
        role(nullable: false)
        visible(nullable: true)
        phone(nullable: true)
        image(nullable: true)
        creationTime(nullable: true)
        modificationTime(nullable: true)

    }
}
```

and when i run  the server console print below logs (it shows `id` as a primary key but i want `people_id` as a primary key) :-

```
Hibernate: create table people (id bigint not null auto_increment, apppassword varchar(255), card varchar(255) not null, creation_time datetime, image tinyblob, modification_time datetime, name varchar(255) not null, people_id varchar(255) not null, phone varchar(255), role varchar(255) not null, visible bit not null, primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

In MySql my DML is :-

```
CREATE TABLE PEOPLE (
    PEOPLE_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    APPPASSWORD VARCHAR(255),
    CARD VARCHAR(255),
    ROLE VARCHAR(255),
    VISIBLE BIT DEFAULT b'1' NOT NULL,
    PHONE VARCHAR(255),
    IMAGE MEDIUMBLOB,
    CREATION_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    MODIFICATION_TIME DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (PEOPLE_ID)
)
```

I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120708/how-to-change-primary-key-column-in-grails)  , but look like this solution is not working for me.
Please help

Comment: Use camelCase for `String peopleId` and `id name: 'peopleId'` otherwise you have to explicitly use `column:` as `id name: 'people_id', column: "PEOPLE_ID", type: 'string'`

Comment: i tried the second solution and tried to access database as People.list()
 i am getting  `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringTypeDescriptor.unwrap(StringTypeDescriptor.java:39
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:64
property.BasicPropertyAccessor HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: com.test.web.domin.People, setter method of property: id
property.BasicPropertyAccessor HHH000091: Expected type: java.lang.Long, actual value: java.lang.String
`

Comment: It is because `peope_id` is not mapped properly as well. It is always a better idea to use camelCase because `peopeId` is automatically mapped to `PEOPLE_ID` in db otherwise you also have to specify `people_id column: "PEOPLE_ID"` and `id` mapping should move to `mapping` block instead of constraints. Also I think I always forget about it to mention, `id name: 'people_id', column: "PEOPLE_ID", generator:'assigned'` . Use generator as assigned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable the natively generated identity value feature in grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622847/disable-the-natively-generated-identity-value-feature-in-grails)

Comment: i switched to solution 1 (`camelCase` )  and its working fine. 
Thanks For Solution.

Comment: i have below product dml :- 
`CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS (
    PRODUCT_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 ...... )`
and stock dml as :- 
` CREATE TABLE STOCK (
    UNIT INT,
    PRODUCT VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PEOPLE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT STOCK _FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_ID),
CONSTRAINT STOCK_FK_3 FOREIGN KEY (PEOPLE) REFERENCES PEOPLE(PEOPLE_ID),
`
i am trying to get Stock.list(); i want only product name and people name(i dont want to load other column data).. how can i get write this thing in Domain model. 
please help.